# How to get rid of the back and forward button in firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

since I'm good with alt+ shortcuts for back and forward the buttons are never useful to me so I want to get rid of them and have more space for other things but I can't find how I can do it, is there any way to get rid of them? btw is there any shortcut for the back list dropdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there any way to get rid of them [back and forward buttons]?

Yes.

Add the following to `userChrome.css`:

> ```
> #back-button, #forward-button {
>   display: none;
> }
> ```

Source [Nightly 58.0a1 - how to hide back/forward buttons?](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3034299)

Note:

- See [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes) for instructions on locating/creating `userChrome.css`

---

#### Is there any shortcut for the back list dropdown?

I don't think so.

There isn't one listed at https://shortcutworld.com which is usually pretty accurate.